# Change saxon processor HE to EE

Tags: java, saxon, calabash

I installed xml calabash successfull on my windows machine.
Running an xpl with 2 xslt transformations and writing the output in a file seems to works fine.

My problem is, that I need some exslt functions that aren't available with HE. I do have an EE version of saxon9, but I can't get it to work.

I installed:

`xmlcalabash-1.1.20-98.zip`

Within the **./xmlcalabash/lib** I added:

`saxon9ee.jar`
`saxon-license.lic`

When I run a xpl (with an exslt function):
**java -classpath "D:/xmltools/Apps/xmlcalabash/xmlcalabash.jar;D:/xmltools/Apps/xmlcalabash/lib/saxon9ee.jar" com.xmlcalabash.drivers.Main --saxon-processor ee .\xpl\testpipe.xpl**

I receive an error:

```
Failed to obtain EE processor; using HE instead.
ERROR: file:/D:/xmltools/Apps/xmlcalabash/xpl/pidadd.xsl:13:7:XPST0017:
Cannot find a 0-argument function named {http://exslt.org/math}random()
ERROR: Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation
ERROR:     cause: Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation
ERROR: Pipeline failed: Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation
ERROR: Underlying exception: Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation
```

Hope someone can help?

Comment: As for a random number generator, Saxon 10 and 11 HE support the XPath 3.1 `random-number-generator` function so perhaps that is an option instead of relying on EXSLT.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I also tried this function, but not get it working.
When I add something like:

`<xsl:variable name="persID">
 <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(current-dateTime(), '[Y0001][M01][D01][H01][m01][s01][f001]BH')"/>
<xsl:for-each select="1 to 11">
<xsl:variable name="dummy"><xsl:element name="b"/></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="randomnumber">
<xsl:value-of select="current-dateTime()"/>
<xsl:value-of select="generate-id($dummy)"/>
</xsl:variable><xsl:value-of select="random-number-generator($randomnumber)?permute(0 to 9)[last()]"/></xsl:for-each></xsl:variable>`

Comment: And I run it with Oxygen I get a nice result: 
<p class="pid">20220404172232834BH22968277024</p>
            
But when I run it within xpl I get the same number:
20220404170005415BH33333333333

Comment: If you need help with using `random-number-generator` perhaps lets agree on doing that in a separate question where we don't need to read complicated code snippets in comments but you can rather provide the details in the question text as formatted code samples.

Comment: Hi Martin, you are right about a new thread. My bad.
I managed with a recursive call-template.

Comment: One interesting way to use `random-number-generator` and XSLT 3 is storing it in an accumulator, that frees you from the effort to use recursion, you initialize it with e.g. `random-number-generator(current-dateTime())`, then write accumulator rules matching those rules where you need a new value use have e.g. `select="$value?next()"` and in the template(s) where you need to use a random number generator you access the current accumuator value e.g. `accumulator-before('accumulator-name')?permute(..)`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try creating an explicit classpath and putting `saxon-license.lic` on that path? I believe the `lib` directory can only be used to find libraries that the Calabash jar expects to find there. It isn't the case that all files placed in there are automatically on the classpath.

Comment: I tried:

**java -classpath "D:/xmltools/Apps/xmlcalabash/xmlcalabash.jar;D:/xmltools/Apps/xmlcalabash/lib/saxon9ee.jar;D:/xmltools/Apps/xmlcalabash/lib/saxon-license.lic" com.xmlcalabash.drivers.Main --saxon-processor ee .\xpl\testpipe.xpl**

but same result